# Huawei mobile services push kit 907122036: no right API call

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

I want to use the Push Kit.. is there something wrong with my configuration or setup?

Environment :

Phone model (Settings > About phone): ANA-NX9 Huawei P40.

EMUI version (Settings > About phone): 11.0.0

HMS Core version number(Settings > Apps > Apps > HMS Core): 6.1.0.314 SDK version number

(app-level build.gradle document): 24

LOGS:
*`*Error/Exception: {"framesToPop":1,"nativeStackAndroid":[],"userInfo":null,"message":"907122036: no right","code":"907122045"}`

Above error whenever I try to getToken via HmsPushInstanceId.getToken('')**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Basically this error(**907122036** ) will come if HUAWEI Push Kit is not enabled.  For details, refer to [Getting Started](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/config-agc-0000001053537946) to check whether the related service is enabled for the app.

[Result Code reference](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References/hmspushresultcode-0000001054391543)

check whether you have enable permission from Manage APIs: **Go to Project settings > Manage APIs and enable Push Kit.**

[How can I check whether HUAWEI Push Kit is enabled for an app?](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/rn-faqs-0000001057278103)
Sign in to AppGallery Connect, select the app to be checked, click Manage APIs, and check whether HUAWEI Push Kit is enabled.

Check the Service status parameter. If its value is Enabled, HUAWEI Push Kit is enabled for the app.

[React native push kit reference sample code](http://%20https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Examples/reactnative-sample-code-0000001050157811)

make sure you are using React Native Push Plugin, download the HMS Core SDK package and integrate it locally.

For the integration process, refer to React Native Development Guide. [latest plugin](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Library/reactnative-plugin-0000001050155850).

Happy coding!!